# dynamically add text to jQuery marquee

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> How to add text in jquery marquee dynamically?

I have tried to append the text to a marquee, it's working but when I add long text, it starts not working properly (The text marquee didn't finish in the middle of animation marquee will be started again even the last text hasn't arrived yet).

my code like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.marquee').marquee({
            //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
            duration: 15000,
            //gap in pixels between the tickers
            gap: 50,
            //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
            delayBeforeStart: 0,
            //'left' or 'right'
            direction: 'left',
            //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
            duplicated: true
        });
      });

 function AppendData(){
            document.getElementById("line").innerHTML += '| MARK | ------------------------------------ THIS IS LONG TEXT I APPEND -------------------------------------------------------------------';
 }
```

```css
.marquee {
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .marquee span.line{
          padding-top: 6px;
          color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
          font-size: 9pt;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="marquee" id="tambah">
      <span class="line" id="line"><span class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
    </div>
  
  <button onclick="AppendData()">Add Text</button>
```

Comment: What you mean by "_it start not working properly_"? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @palaѕн it's mean the text haven't finish yet to show, but the animation marquee start showing text from begining again

Comment: @palaѕн it's kinda have some limit width, but idk how to make the width is auto by the long of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marquee.js seems to be really futsy. This should get you close to where you'd like to be. I can't keep working on it, but I wanted to at least put you in the right direction. Before its invocation, you can `.bind()` an event called `finished` that will destroy the old marquee, reset data, and resume the marquee. However, there doesn't seem to be any looping options that don't make it restart from the right of the screen, so it jumps. I'm sure there's something you can do with this. Please look at the event part of Marquee.js' documentation for more info.

https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee#events

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const options = {
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 2000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 50,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
  };
  const textToAdd = '| MARK | ------------------------------------ THIS IS LONG TEXT I APPEND -------------------------------------------------------------------';
  var addLine = false;
  const line = $("#line");
  const btn = $("#btn");
  
  $('.marquee').bind('finished', function() {
    if (addLine == true) {
      var newLine = $("#line").innerHTML += textToAdd;
      $(this).marquee('destroy').append(newLine);
      $('.marquee').marquee(options);
      
    }
  }).marquee(options);

  btn.on("click", function appendData() {
    addLine = true;
  });


});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee span.line {
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="marquee" id="tambah">
  <span class="line" id="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>

<button id="btn">Add Text</button>
```

Comment: the problem is i have to append text in the running text before its disappear from left to right not waiting until it's finished

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation that aides that. I don't even see a way to detect it in their documentation. You'd have to watch the position of the span, and by that time, you've gone way beyond marquee, where you could probably best do it with a custom solution with css animation states.

Comment: yeah, i have been seen the document too and i don't find it either, but if i watch the position and i change text when it's disappear the problem if the lenght of the text doesn't same with text before than the text behind will move suddenly when it's shother before or longer, and i have tried with costum css animation, and i got the same problem when text is too long then the animation will be start again before its finished

Comment: Maybe use an intersection observer?

Comment: The other issue you're going to run into is the fact that the length is based on the size of the text box, so your speed is going to be inconsistent as well. The longer it is, the faster it's going to move.

Comment: i never heard before, can you give me an example?

Comment: yaps, thats the problems too, i have tried so many way and the problem is always with a width problems except using maruqee tags, but the problem with marquee tags is that when i append text on marquee tags the first animation only run on until text before append and will start again then the animation will running fully until finished

Comment: Let me see if I can code a snippet that will do it. It would involve creating a clone and then adding it in when it leaves the scrollrect of the window. Give me one sec. :)

Comment: oke thanks a lot for helping me dude, let me know if you're done :)

Comment: It's definitely a rabbit hole. Every time I think I have a solution, some gotcha appears. You'd have to come up with a normalization algorithm to keep the speed the same. You'd also have to create an animation queue because many clicks might happen before the initial animation finishes. It's definitely a challenge. Haha

Comment: thanks for helping me, finally i have better solution to handle it.

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?